# Jasmine tests throw error with Decorators using the Injector manually in Angular 4+

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, jasmine, decorator

We are using the injector from `AppModule.injector` in some of our Decorators. Everything works fine except for when we run tests that include such a Decorator at some point:
`Uncaught TypeError: enum_decorator_1.Enum is not a function` while Enum() is the Decorator name.

```
export class AppModule {

    static injector: Injector;
    static changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef;

    constructor(public injector: Injector) {
        AppModule.injector = injector;
    }
}
```

I assume the bootstrapping in tests works differently and the injector isn't available for some reason. When I comment out the parts regarding the AppModule.injector in the Decorator, everything works.

The test code itself doesn't matter. What happens is this:

1. I initialize a Service `fileService = new FileService(communicationServiceMock);`
2. That service imports an exported const variable
3. That const variable imports a class that is decorated with Enum() decorator

So the instantiation of the service which accesses the decorator at some point triggers the error.

Has anyone faced similar problems?

Comment: update your testing code to the post

Comment: I updated with some info about the test code. The tests itself don't matter tho. It must be the initialisation of the service under test.

Comment: where is that ? code?

Comment: As I said, the test code should be irrelevant, but here it is:
https://pastebin.com/t5bCKB9A